# Vuforia SDK How to make 3d object position depend on image position

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3d, vuforia

I'm newbie at Vuforia SDK. I have set a 3d object as a child of image target. But when I try to view the results, a 3d object is displayed in some static position. And I want 3d object to be displayed in position right [on the top of image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bMVcf.png), wherever it's show. How may I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how it works. The image is used to define a position and a rotation for the camera. Vuforia performs some pattern recognition and calculation to retrieve those info. The object is positioned at 0,0,0 with identity rotation and the Vuforia camera is positioned somewhere in the scene based on the calculation.

If you need the object to be rendered at different location, then you can position the child object wherever you want it to be. In your case, I guess you would have to set the child object with a Y offset so it appears a bit higher.

Comment: can u plz elaborate it more..!!